# Android Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 1, fault addr 0xb8509ce1 in tid 32190 (com.example)

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, runtime-error, push-back

In my app, I use of C++ code to complie.There is a function in xxx.cpp like this:

```
void Cache::addRequest(SREQUEST req)
{
    m_reqs.push_back(req);
}
```

When my app call this function, it's throw the run-time error:

```
Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 1, fault addr 0xb8509ce1 in tid 32190 (com.example)
```

The attribute "m_reqs" is a vector object, which decleared in head file(xxx.h):

```
vector<SREQUEST> m_reqs;

struct SREQUEST
{
    SREQUEST()
    {
        code = "";
        oldLen = 0;
    }
    TimeRound tr;          // enum(int type)
    std::string code;
    int oldLen;
};
```

I use singleton mode with the class "Cache".

```
Cache* Cache::getInstance()
{
     static Cache* _instance;
     // init
     if (_instance == NULL) 
     {
         _instance = new Cache();
     }

     // return the pointer
     return _instance;
}
```

The error is only throwed by real phone, not simulator.I found the solution, but I didn't know what causes this question.I mean it's always appear:

```
SREQUEST req;
req.code = "123";
req.tr = 1;
req.oldLen = 0;
Cache::getInstance()->addRequest(req); // cause error
```

I fix it like:

```
typedef vector<SREQUEST> VEC_SREQUEST;
VEC_SREQUEST* Cache::getVector()
{
    if(v_reqs == 0)     // int type
    {
        vector<SREQUEST>* TEMP = new vector<SREQUEST>();
        void* x = (void*)TEMP;
        v_reqs = (int)x;
    }
    void* temp = (void*)v_reqs;
    VEC_SREQUEST* res = ((VEC_SREQUEST*)temp);
    return res;
}

void Cache::addRequest(SREQUEST req)
{
    VEC_SREQUEST* vec = getVector();
    vec->push_back(req);
}
```

In my cpp, I have been extensively using the code "xxx.push_back(something)". Use this solution the job that needs a lot of time.

So what causes "xxx.push_back" can not work?
And without a large modify how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the reason.

I declear the vector object at the bottom of xxx.h file.The function statement is wroted at first.

Exchanged the postion， everything is ok!